# What does wicket:scope attribute do?

Tags: wicket

There's no documentation for it https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/wickets-xhtml-tags.html#Wicket%2527sXHTMLtags-Attributewicket%253Ascope. Does it work only for components?

Comment: According to the source, it is a kind of namespace for HeaderPartContainer. What are you trying to archive?

Comment: I want see if it's suitable for conditional include of headers for example.

Comment: @bert Can I tweak this scope somehow in sense that it parametrizes an Application.

Comment: Never used this attribute, but, from looking at the source it looks like its used to prevent adding the same header twice in some rare circumstances. Perhaps you can describe your use case?

Comment: For my use-case I found a solution using Application#mountResource() to make a conditional include of resources but have only one page template. Now the question is more general and it's not bound to my use-case. Duplication prevention - this is an analog of CssResourceReference with two String parameters but without writing source code. The hint for you is that this attribute is only available in components (children).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What does wicket:scope attribute do?**
The HtmlHeaderContainer class documents the wicket:scope attribute:

> wicket:head tags (components) must only be added once. To allow for a little bit more control, each wicket:head has an associated scope which by default is equal to the java class name directly associated with the markup which contains the wicket:head. It can be modified by means of the scope attribute.

It is further documented in the HeaderPartContainer class simply stating that it is "A kind of namespace."

**Does it work only for components?**
The wicket:scope attribute is used only for the  tag.  The  tag should only be used in "Panels, Borders and inherited markup (of Panels, Borders and Pages)", as documented in the HtmlHeaderContainer class level javadoc.

In short, the answer to your question is no, the attribute can be used within  tags inside of Pages that inherit markup from a parent.  The implication here is that a  tag only makes sense where you wouldn't just use a  tag (meaning in the base page html file).

Comment: Does make sense. Although I would like to have the same note on `wicket:scope` doc :). Thanks